# why do we use 'prepared' in a sentence like this

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, past-tense

The sentence below says something that's yet to happen, but the word *prepared* is in the past tense. Any suggestions on what to read to understand this will highly be appreciated. Thank you.

> Always be prepared for the unexpected

I also heard someone in a movie say: "She be presented on her birthday"

Comment: The quote you give makes no sense.  At the very least it's missing punctuation.

Comment: Hi, as I commented to your first question, your question seems to be too basic for this community. For future questions, I'd like to advise you to visit our sister site [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/), but please make sure you take the [tour](http://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit their [Help Center](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help) before posting any question. Please don't post the same question on English Language Learners.

Answer (score 2):

Although **prepared** can be a past tense conjugation of the verb prepare, it can also be made into an imperative (command) by putting "be" before it. This makes it a past participle as an adjective meaning

> be ready for something that is likely to happen done or made beforehand

In this case, it's not being used as a past tense verb.

You can see this definition in various dictionaries: the Cambridge English Dictionary, the Oxford English Dictionary, even online ones like the free dictionary.

Comment: Thank @John Clifford, but in most of the examples I see, they use "be" before the adjective. Is that a rule? John Clifford

Comment: Well "be [adjective]" is basically telling the listener that you want them to transition into the state that adjective represents (man it's hard to think of a way to describe this without actually using the word "be"). If I tell you to "be prepared" I want you ready for something to happen (in this case, what you don't expect).

Comment: No it is not a rule; but many adjectives formed from past participles (such as _prepared_) are more often used predicatively than attributively; that is, it is more common to say that something is/was/will be prepared than to talk about "a prepared thing". For that reason, many (probably most) instances of "prepared" are preceded by a part of "be".

Comment: "Be prepared" is the imperative of to be + prepared ( past participle as adjective).

Comment: I can't believe I forgot what an imperative was. I'll edit.